Rust and Redis Stream
Currently trying to make 2 services communicate.
[package]
name = "api"
version = "1.0.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
redis = { version = "0.21.4", features = ["aio", "tokio-comp"] }
...

let _: () = conn.xadd("blockhash_stream", "*", &[
                ("mystream", "test".as_str().unwrap())
            ]).await.expect("Failed to add to Redis stream");

At the moment using
let stream_key = "mystream";
let entries: Vec<RedisResult> = con
            .xrange_all(&[stream_key])
            .await
            .expect("Failed to read stream");
    println!("{:?}", entries)


print me:
[
 StreamReadReply { keys: [] }, StreamReadReply { keys: [] }, StreamReadReply { keys: [] },
 StreamReadReply { keys: [] }, StreamReadReply { keys: [] }, StreamReadReply { keys: [] },
 StreamReadReply { keys: [] }, StreamReadReply { keys: [] }, StreamReadReply { keys: [] }
]

How could i properly read the content of my stream ?
